# What is base object in javascript

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions#14-all-object-have-prototypes
All objects have prototypes, except for the base object. What is base object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The base object is [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype):

> The `Object.prototype` is a property of the Object constructor. **And it is also the end of a prototype chain.**

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype));
```

Most objects inherit from some prototype, which may inherit from some other prototype, eventually ending at `Object.prototype`.

```js
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Number.prototype) === Object.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(5)) === Object.prototype
);
```

That said, the text in your link isn't *entirely* accurate - it's possible to create objects which do not ultimately inherit from `Object.prototype`, eg:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

This can be done to avoid (probably unusual) name collisions for `Object.prototype` methods, which can [cause bugs](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5e62us/is_there_a_reason_to_create_an_object_without_a/).